# How to make a get request with a URL-encoded object in angular?

Tags: ajax, angular, get, urlencode

I have a complex object:

```
{
valueA:'a',
value_array: {
   'v': {value:1, value:2},
   'v2': {value:1, value:2},
 }
}
```

How can I send it in a get request as url-encoded string in angular's http service ?

The results should be query string that represents a nested json object, similar to this:

```
api_call?value_list[585588558][sim_type]=existing&value_list[585588558][secondary_sim_type]=new&value_list[587788778][sim_type]=existing
```

Thanks,
Yaron

Comment: I think this is an still open issue on the repo:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20298

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there's a way to achieve it with an angular class but I managed to solve it with an external npm package - 'qs';
I install the package and then :

```
import * as qs from 'qs';
const qsParams = qs.stringify(nestedJSON);
```

Answer (score -3):

You simply should not use GET for this case, try to use [post](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request) instead.

Comment: Let's say I am sending a GET with a complex filter object ?

Comment: I tried but I don't see that it can parse nested JSON.

Comment: have you tried to use: `new HttpParams({ fromObject: myObject });`

Comment: I have but it doesn't parse well a deeply nested JSON object. I ended up using an external library and it worked well - 'qs' (I answered my own question with an example above). Thank you for your help !